# In SQL injection why don't we use OR 1 or OR 2>1 instead of OR 1=1?

Tags: sql-injection

I read everywhere regarding SQL injection where it is said that if SQL query is:

`SELECT * FROM table_name where username='xxxxx' AND password ='xxxx'`

and if you want to enter always true condition then you will have to use `'OR 1=1--` then the query will be:

`SELECT * FROM table_name where username=''OR 1=1--' AND password ='xxxx'`

The logic behind the SQL query is simple since OR `1=1` is always true that is why it has been executed. However `2>1`, `3>2` will always be considered true but why don't we use `'OR 2>1`,`'OR 1` expression in SQL injection?

Comment: No one says that you ***have to use*** `OR 1=1`. It's just easier to explain for those who are new, and because it's "expected", then even experts understand what the clause is meant to do.

Comment: You orignally tagged this with OWASP Top 10. Even OWASP's documentation uses an ***example*** clause of `'a'='a'`. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection So, it appears that or premise for the question is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a simple string used to test the SQL statement. There's no requirement to use `1=1` exactly. Like you say `5>3` would work in the exact same way.

Unfortunately `1=1` is so common that it triggers protection code. Weakly protected code *could* be vulnerable to SQL injection and fail the `or 1=1;` test. So it does make sense to vary sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any expression that evaluates to true, it doesn't have to be `1=1`, I don't think SQL contains a literal value for true according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170688/sql-server-boolean-literal).

`1=1` is the easiest for me to write and I got used to it.